# Viewstatemode / Textbox, persisting despite being disabled? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I've set ViewStateMode="Disabled" on a textbox, however when I perform any postback action, when the page loads again it's text value is still retained.

Have I misunderstood this property?

Assigning it `string.empty` on postback seems abit over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2004/03/15/2273.aspx). It explains very well why the text is being persisted even if ViewState is disabled. So you don't come around assigning to it `String.Empty` on postback.

Comment: The link is helpful although the content itself is written poorly.

I assume he's trying to say, '...because TextBox implemenets IPostBackDataHandler it populates its value from the values POSTed aswell as the ViewState (if viewstatemode is not disabled)'